Loop through filtered sheet when only one row returned
My code is designed to loop through a filtered sheet.
I noticed when the filter results in only one visible row, instead of progressing through the rows, it seems to cycle through the same row index while iterating across columns rather than rows.
I checked other variables, and this behavior only occurs with a single-row filter result.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RCM Filtered")  
ws.AutoFilterMode = False 
ws.Range("A1:CV1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("BP Business Process", "ITGC IT General Control"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ws.Range("A1:CV1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("Lean"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

On Error Resume Next 
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim filteredRange As Range
Set filteredRange = ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0 ' Ripristinare la gestione degli errori normale
   
If filteredRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nessuna riga trovata dopo il filtro."
    Exit Sub
End If
 
' Scorrere le righe filtrate
For Each cell In filteredRange
    Dim i As Long
    i = cell.Row
    [...]


I think .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) misbehaves when you call it on a single cell.

What you suggest to solve this issue?

You could always check If lastRow = 2 or If ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Count = 1

Yes but how can I loop in that row I need?

Add If lastRow = 2 Then Set filteredRange = ws.Range("E2") before For Each cell In filteredRange
